# Overriding methods in superclasses that use composition?

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

*Clarification:
My question is not about overriding vs overloading functions. It's about overriding methods in superclasses that use composition.*

Lets say I have two classes, `A` and `B`. They're really useful together, so I make another class composed of the two, called `AB`. The problem with this is that subclasses of `AB` have difficulty overriding `A/B`'s methods. I'm looking for suggestions on how to mitigate the effect described below.

### Example:

`A`: Has a function that calls another one of its own functions. In this case, `loopA(int num)` loops and performs `a()` num times.

```
public class A {
    public void loopA(int num){       
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){   
            a();
        }
    }

    public void a(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

`B`: Just random functionality.

```
public class B {
    public void b(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

`AB`: A combination of the two.

```
public class AB {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    public void loopA(int num){
        a.loopA(num);
    }

    public void a(){
        a.a();
    }

    public void b(){
        b.b();
    }
}
```

`ValidatedAB`: `AB` that validates before performing `a()`

```
public class ValidatedAB extends AB{
    @Override
    public void a(){
        System.out.println("Validate A!");
        super.a();
    }
}
```

### Problem

My problem is that calling `ValidatedAB.loopA(int num)` will NOT call the overridden `a()` in `ValidatedAB`, but the original `A.a()`.

```
    ValidatedAB vab = new ValidatedAB();
    vab.loopA(2);

    //Desired Output:
    Validate A!
    A
    Validate A!
    A

    //Actual Output:
    A
    A
```

### Possible Solutions

**1. Copy/Paste or Refactor A and B into AB**

A simple solution that gets rid of composition but results in a large `AB` class, and is also code duplication if we keep `A`, `B`, and `AB`.

**2. Subclass A and B separately, and inject both into ValidatedAB.**

```
public class ValidatedA extends A {
    @Override
    public void a(){
        System.out.println("Validate A!");
        super.a();
    }
}

public class ValidatedAB extends AB{
    public ValidatedAB(A a, B b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

ValidatedAB vab = new ValidatedAB(new ValidatedA(), new B());
vab.loopA(2);
```

This will cause a lot of classes to be made (my team members hate that). It also exposes the fact that `AB` is a composition of `A` and `B` (not a terrible thing in this scenario considering `AB` has the same interfaces, but otherwise would probably get some dirty looks). Finally, it still has the same overriding problem if `ValidatedAB` is subclassed.

### Conclusion

I'm hoping to find a clean, non-bulky, encapsulated way to achieve the effect I'm trying to get, but I know there are always trade offs. As a junior developer, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why this was marked as a duplicate for the difference between overloading and overriding. That's not my problem here. My question is about overriding methods in superclasses that use composition.

Comment: I've renamed a(int num) to loopA(int num) to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It does override the method `a()` but not the method `a(int)` - just add an additional override for the method with its parameters or add the parameter to your override.

Java sees both method as different ones.

Comment: I'm not looking at a() and a(int); I'm looking at a(int) calling a() in a combination of composition and subclassing the composed superclass.